# My business not appearing in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business

I have a business, which I have added as well as verified. I have also added two reviews from my side. But still even after an year, it doesn't independently shows up when I look for my area. For it to ever show up, I have to search for it. This isn't what I expected. What am I missing?

[image: Google Maps screen shot]

Here, you can see various places, businesses that show without them being searched for specifically. Mine just won't show up. I have to type in the search box and then it will show up. That's the issue.

Comment: Does the correct information (hours open etc) show up when someone searches by name? Did you also already set up a G+ page for your business?

Answer (score 2):

Having Google My Business Page doesn't necessarily mean that your business will show up in Google Maps as a place label (i.e., show on the map without a user searching).

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6056435?hl=en&ref_topic=4854129):

> The place labels shown on Google Maps are determined algorithmically based on a large number of factors. One factor these algorithms consider is the accuracy of the business information and the richness of the content associated with the business.
>
> Verifying your business improves the chances that your business will
>   display with a place label.

The key part is that verifying your business **does not guarantee** that it will show up, but it does improve your odds.

Comment: Really? Google needs to put some qualifications requirement there for it to show up!